# WP Query : strange behaviour with multiple no-hierarchical tax

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query

II dont' understand my query's behaviour.
I try to display posts with a tax.
Ok, very common.
Here is my code :
 

`$myTools = get_the_term_list( $post->ID,'tool');
echo $myTools;//just to test
   $args_technique = array(
     'post_type' => 'technic', // my custom post
     'posts_per_page' => 4, // How many items to display
     'no_found_rows'  => true,// no pagination to speed up the query
     'tax_query' => array(
     'relation' => 'AND',
          array(
             'taxonomy' => 'tool',
             'field'    => 'name',
             'terms'    => $myTools
            )
          ), 
     );
//My loop
$technique_query = new wp_query( $args_technique );
if ( $technique_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    while ( $technique_query->have_posts() ) {
     $technique_query->the_post(); ?>
       the_post_thumbnail();
       the_title(); 
    }// End while 
wp_reset_postdata();
}//end if`

It works.
BUT only if I have just ONE term from my taxonomy 'tools'.
As soon as I add another term, it doesnt' display anything...
My echo test works (= it displays well the different terms), but not post...

I made a try with `foreach` instead of `while`.
Same miss...
I took a look at my BDD, but it seems normal.
Could this be because my registered tax is non hierarchical ?
Could someone show me my mistake(s) ?
Tranks a lot

Comment: I guess (?) that my problem is that my tax_query_term is an array.

There's a similar question about here : 
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102048/why-is-my-wp-query-not-working-when-tax-query-terms-are-an-array

But, even with the answer, I'm still stucked...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it, sorry for the noise !...
`//fetch the terms of my tax
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'tool'); 
$terms_ids = []; //an array, which can contain several terms
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   $terms_ids[] = $term->term_id;
   }

// Query
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'technical_post',
   'posts_per_page' => 4, // How many items to display
   'tax_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'tool',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => array($term->term_id)     )
   ),
);
// Query posts
$tech_query = new wp_query( $args );
   // Loop through posts
   foreach( $tech_query->posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
      the_title();
   // End loop
   endforeach;`

// Reset post data
wp_reset_postdata();

Comment: Zut... Actually it doesn't work... Could anyone take some time (sorry) to look at my disorder ? Thanks